# C# Regex.Replace() swallowing part of original string

Tags: c#, regex

I can't figure out what happens to the `"FROM ROOT"` when the `Regex.Replace()` happens:

```
static string query = @"
SELECT * 
FROM root
ORDER BY root['UtcTimestamp'] DESC";

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var endsWithOrderBy = new Regex("^.+(\\s+ORDER\\s+BY\\s+.+)$",
        RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);

    query = query.Trim();

    var result = endsWithOrderBy.Replace(query, "$1");

    Console.Write(result);
    Console.Read();
}
```

I think it's because there's a `\n` instead of a space between `"FROM root\nORDER BY"`. How can I tell the regex to include `\n` characters in `\\s`?

NOTE: Please refrain from discussions about the applicability of using regular expressions here, given that the example here is contrived.

Comment: What is your expected behavior here? What are you trying to do?

Comment: `\s` matches all kinds of whitespace characters, including `\n`.  So that's definitely not your problem, but I don't get what you're trying to do.  If you want the regex to match the whole string, add the `Singleline` option; if you want to match just last line, remove the `^.+` and the first `\s+`.  And while you're at it, use verbatim string literals (`@"..."`) so you don't have to escape the backslashes, and drop the `Compiled` option: you don't need it.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5181w5w.aspx), since you've specified `RegexOptions.Multiline`, the `^` anchor matches the beginning of a line, not the beginning of the string.

As a result, your pattern matches:

```
FROM root
ORDER BY root['UtcTimestamp'] DESC
```

You then replace that with the value of the first capture, which is:

```
{\n}
ORDER BY root['UtcTimestamp'] DESC
```

which gives the result:

```
SELECT *

ORDER BY root['UtcTimestamp'] DESC
```

It's not clear what output you were expecting. If you just want to remove the entire `ORDER BY` clause, then add a group to capture the prefix:

```
var endsWithOrderBy = new Regex("^(.+)(\\s+ORDER\\s+BY\\s+.+)$", ...);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
\s*\n?\s*(ORDER\s+BY\s+.*)$
```

If you use an anchor for the start of the line (`^`) you cannot match when the `ORDER BY` is not preceded by a line break, i.e. `SELECT * FROM root ORDER BY root['UtcTimestamp'] DESC`.

Check here: https://regex101.com/r/gQ2rQ1/2

I'm using the `g` modifier so you can test multiple sentences, but you won't need it.